# How to create new "destination library" when uploading files?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, file-upload, library

Please check the following screenshot. I am trying to upload a file and you can see it gives me option to select from one of those three destination libraries. But how do I create a new one?
I don't want to use these and want to create my own destination library.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Create a new destination library go to "Site Contents" -> "add an app" -> "Document Library".
This will create a new document library and will be visible in "Destination Library" drop down.